# How to import "|" delimited CSV data from a Bucket to MySQL on Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, mysql-workbench, import-from-csv

I am trying to import data from a CSV file that is stored in a Bucket. The CSV file uses the "|" delimiter. I would like to import these data to a MySQL database on Cloud SQL.

However, I found out that the root user by default does not have the "File" privilege, which means I cannot perform this import via MySQL Workbench.

I tried to use the command `LOAD DATA INFILE`, but I got the following error:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)`

I also tried to use the tool `gcloud sql import csv`, but I got another error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.sql.import.csv) HTTPError 403: The service account does not have the required permissions for the bucket.`

I do not know how to solve this problem. Could anyone help me with this? Any suggestion or guidance would be very welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: As mentioned in this Troubleshooting [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export#troubleshooting-export) Ensure that the bucket exists and the service account for the Cloud SQL instance (which is performing the export) has the Storage Object Creator role (roles/storage.objectCreator) to allow export to the bucket.

Comment: Yes, I Have. Tks

Comment: Permission is the first problem; talk to your Cloud provider.  The second is the use of `FIELDS SEPARATED BY "|"`.

Comment: check if you have  `roles/storage.objectAdmin` role  as mentioned in this [link1](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Databases/Export-with-gcloud-sql-export-but-service-role-with-storage/m-p/627349),also check this  [link2](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/permissions-for-google-cloud-sql-import-using-service-accounts#gcloud-sql-import-csv-fails-with-permissions-error-when-import-file-contains-wildcard)

Answer (score 0):

You could try reformatting your CSV file to be delimited by something else, e.g. `,`?

Comment: No, why do I have fields in records that contain ",".